# Find Parent ID by Giving Sponsor ID in recursive way using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, binary-tree

I'm Currently trying to make a binary tree and Currently My SQL table structure looks like this

```
Node_ID  Parent_ID  Node_Position  SID     
-------  ---------  -------------  --------
      1          0  T                      
      2          1  L              1       
      3          1  R              1       
      4          2  L              1       
      5          2  R              1       
      6          3  L              1       
      7          3  R              1       
      8          4  L              1       
      9          4  R              1       
     10          5  L              1       
     11          5  R              1       
     12          8  L              1
```

which creates the below hand made tree and Here's [an image link](https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-mFL6hZwQNrQ/XFx2eKp0PbI/AAAAAAAAAhM/JuIRZR-PrT4WDl9BIbVapzTeH0B7JJVLwCLcBGAs/s640/tree.png).

```
                                1 
                             /    \
                            2       3
                           / \      / \
                          4   5     6  7
                        /\    / \   
                        8 9   10 11
                       /
                      12
```

Issue in this tree I'm getting so far when i fill both childs of id 4 and 5 and instead of getting next parent id of SID 1 which is 6 it gets parent ID of 8 which is not the behavior of binary tree

The php Code for getting parent id of new child on the basis of sponsor id. Which I done so far is below

```
function getNodeInsertPostionByParentId($parentId){
$position = array('status'=>false);
        $parents = array();
        foreach($parentId as $parent){              
                $qry = "select Node_ID,Node_Position from tblregister where Parent_ID =".$parent." order by Node_Position asc";
                $rst = mysql_query($qry);
                $count = mysql_num_rows($rst);
                if($count==2){
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rst)){
                        $parents[$parent][] = $row['Node_ID'];
                    }   
                }elseif($count==1){
                    $position['status'] = true;
                    $position['parentId'] = $parent;
                    $position['node'] = 'R';
                    //echo '<pre>1';print_r($position);echo '</pre>';
                    return $position;
                }else{
                    $position['status'] = true;
                    $position['parentId'] = $parent;
                    $position['node'] = 'L';
                    //echo '<pre>2';print_r($position);echo '</pre>';
                    return $position;
                }
            }

        return searchByParents($parents);
    }


    function searchByParents($parents){

        foreach($parents as $parent){
            return getNodeInsertPostionByParentId($parent);  
        }
    } 

getNodeInsertPostionByParentId(array('1'));
```

Actually So far I'm trying to get newly child parent ID on the basis of SID. I don't know what to do . . . I'm thinking Should I have to check whether the level has all the childs or not . . or there is another way to solve this problem

Comment: I hate to be that person, but why are you using that structure for storing hierarchical data? Would you not be better of using nested set or adjacency list?

Comment: This problem is new to me so I've searched a lot and get recursive method to find parent id on the basis of their Sponsor ids, , ,, can you show me some of nested set or adjancey list ? ? ?

Comment: @Layke any help or suggestion !